# Sepia filter for display output on OS X

Tags: macos, mac, color-profiles

So I have a windows PC and a MacBook Pro... For no reasonable reason, I want to put everything in Sepia, dim the brightness as much as possible and switch off all the lights...

I've achieved this with ease on the Windows PC, (as I could simply change the monitor's color overlay from 'none' to 'sepia'), but how do I do this on the MacBook Pro?

I've gathered that it has something to do with the color profiles, and I figure that all I have to do is find a sepia color profile and just tell the mac to use that one instead...

Problems so far:

- Doing it myself by creating a new profile is a headache (the steps that Apple puts me through are pretty painful)
- Looking for it online has returned no meaningful results... :-(

Comment: @MaxMackie - What did you edit? Just so I know...

Comment: I changed "sephia" to "sepia" in the title. A minor edit.

Comment: No worries, happens all the time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply a color filter (and reduce screen brightness) with [Nocturne](http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-nocturne/):

[image: Nocturne]

Comment: Lol, yes... This did it.. It was also pretty trippy cycling through all the tint colors while in night mode...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the cross-platform [f.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/) to change the white color temperature on your system, even have it happen automatically based on time (i.e. during the night).

[image: flux mac os x app]